# Customisable Columns in a HTML table based on the user (Persisted)

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc, datatable, thymeleaf

How to make a HTML table to customisable (choose the columns which should be viewed) based on the user's selection and the selection should be persistent?

The user should be able to select the columns they want to view once and every single time they login they should view those columns only. The columns that are being viewed should be changed only when the user updates the list of columns they want to view.

I have created something similar to this - [DataTables Show / hide columns dynamically](https://datatables.net/examples/api/show_hide.html). But in this the user have to select the columns every single time. **How can I make the changes persistent?**

Attaching below the code for reference

HTML:

```
<div class="row" id="calendarMainView">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr></hr>
        <div>
            Choose columns:
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="1">BILLBOARD</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="2">TABLET PN</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="3">WS</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="4">INSIDER</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="5">FA&amp;G</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="6">SPOTLIGHT</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="7">TUNE-IN</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="8">NEWSLETTER</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="9">FR HOME</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="10">FR MOVIES</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="11">FR TV</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="12">FR APPS</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="13">FR GAMES</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="14">FR Live</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="15">CLP</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="16">Ambient Card</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="17">Video Card</a> -
            <a class="toggle-vis" href="" data-column="18">DEVELOPER REQUESTS</a>
        </div>
        <table id="all_table" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>WEEK</th>
                <th>BILLBOARD</th>
                <th>TABLET PN</th>
                <th>WS</th>
                <th>INSIDER</th>
                <th>FA&amp;G</th>
                <th>SPOTLIGHT</th>
                <th>TUNE-IN</th>
                <th>NEWSLETTER</th>
                <th>FR HOME</th>
                <th>FR MOVIES</th>
                <th>FR TV</th>
                <th>FR APPS</th>
                <th>FR GAMES</th>
                <th>FR Live</th>
                <th>CLP</th>
                <th>Ambient Card</th>
                <th>Video Card</th>
                <th>DEVELOPER REQUESTS</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr th:each="instance : ${placementCountMap}">
                <td th:text="${instance.key.toString()}" />
                <td th:each="placementType : ${T(cms.library.model.PlacementType).values()}">
                    <a th:text="${instance.value.get(placementType.name())}"
                       th:href="@{|/rubicon/__${marketplace}__/week/__${year}__-__${instance.key.getWeekNum()}__#${placementType.name()}|}" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a th:text="${instance.value.get('DEVELOPER_REQUESTS')}"
                       th:href="@{/rubicon/__${marketplace}__/week/__${year}__-__${instance.key.getWeekNum()}__#DEVELOPER_REQUESTS}"/>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var table = $('#all_table').DataTable({
        searching: false,
        paging: false,
        info: false,
    });
    customiseCalendarView(table);
});
 
/***
Function to customise the table in Calendar View
 */
 
function customiseCalendarView(table) {
    $('a.toggle-vis').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
 
        var column = table.column($(this).attr('data-column'));
 
        column.visible(!column.visible());
    });
}
```

Comment: The information must be stored somewhere like a database or at least a cookie...

Comment: Looking at the linked example in your question: DataTables uses [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) for saving changes. See their [`stateSave`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave) option. See [`state()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/state()) for what gets saved. You can customize the storage location to be whatever you prefer.